# How do I keep a shared data structure in-memory between Django Requests

Tags: python, django, caching

My Django application is extremely performance sensitive and all requests require access to the same data structure. How do I store the data structure in such a way that it is accessible to all the requests?

Background:

I'm currently using the cache backend. This is a bit slow because the DS is large and it has to be retrieved and unpickled each time.

I understand that HTTP interactions should be stateless and knowingly need to break this constraint. Nothing bad should happen because it's read-only right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a several ways to deal with this issue:

1. Move the data structure out of Python completely (rather than loading it from a storage medium every time).  For example, if your structure is conducive to it you could store it in [Redis](http://redis.io/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), [Riak](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/), or [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/). (As a bonus, you get the ability to query the data, if you need that ability).
2. Move the structure to a separate process and communicate with it using a pipe or [queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).
3. Use a [memory mapped file](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) to share the data.

HTTP is stateless, but that doesn't mean that you can't preserve state between requests.  You just have to do the work yourself (at the application level).  The protocol doesn't do it for you.  *Ideally* you avoid the state, as it makes it easier to scale horizontally, but not every application is *easy* to scale

Comment: The majority of the cost seems to be pickling/unpickling the structure. I've tried using Redis but the same bottle neck occurs. I'll give (2) and (3) a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @ldinh - if you are storing the data in any of the above-listed stores you will *not* want to pickle it.  Instead you will want to translate it into the appropriate data structure to store in Redis (if that's your pick) and query it from redis.

Comment: Ah, that is much smarter. We'll have to flatten our DS a little but now I have 3 things to try. =]

Answer (score 3):

Django, and probably the majority of web applications, use [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/). Of course the efficacy of caching depends on how you use it, i.e. by storing the data retrieved most frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Really useful and informative article on caching in Django [here](http://codysoyland.com/2010/jan/17/evaluating-django-caching-options/). Gives quantified speed improvements. Amazing how much faster you can get with a little tweaking.